# How to convert TIMESTAMP to UTC milliseconds in ESQL

Tags: datetime, unix-timestamp, extended-sql

Is there an ESQL function to convert TIMESTAMP to UTC milliseconds?

This is what I did:

```
DECLARE eventTimeInteger INTEGER CAST ((eventTimeStamp - epochTimeStamp) SECOND as INTEGER);
```

But I keep getting this error. So I suspect the "-" is an issue but I'm not sure how else to go about this.

BIP2420E: (.Event_SeparateMessages.Main, 142.60) : Invalid or incompatible data types for '-' operator.

Either the data types of the operands of the operator were not valid for the operator, or the datatypes were incompatible.

Correct the syntax of your ESQL expression in node '.Event_SeparateMessages.Main', around line and column '142.60', then redeploy the message flow: Ensure that the data types of the operands are valid and compatible with each other.

This below is what I've tried but it won't even deploy.

```
--Converting time in string to timestamp
DECLARE source CHARACTER eventTime ;
DECLARE eventTimeStamp CHARACTER;
DECLARE pattern CHARACTER 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSS''Z';
SET eventTimeStamp = CAST(source AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT pattern);
DECLARE epochTimeStamp TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00';

--Casting time from timestamp to Integer                       
DECLARE eventTimeInteger INTEGER CAST ((eventTimeStamp - epochTimeStamp) SECOND as INTEGER);
```

I need to have "eventTimeInteger" give me the timestamp in seconds.

Comment: Please do _not_ use the [tag:esql] tag.  Please identify the DBMS you are working with in one tag, and if embedded SQL is appropriate, then please use [tag:embedded-sql] instead of [tag:esql].  I'd suggest that [tag:datetime] is more appropriate than [tag:integration] — and I'm not sure whether [tag:unix-timestamp] is really appropriate.  I've made some tag changes; please edit your question to add the correct DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, if I'm reading your code right, is that you are trying to subtract a `TIMESTAMP` from a `CHARACTER` set.

*edit: Noticed the change SET for eventTimeStamp, however the date math is still going to given an* `INTERVAL` *output, not an* `INTEGER`

```
DECLARE EpocTimeStamp TIMESTAMP; 
DECLARE eventTimeStamp INTERVAL; 

SET EpocTimeStamp = TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'; 
SET eventTimeStamp = (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - EpocTimeStamp) SECOND * 1000;
CAST(eventTimeStamp AS INTEGER);
```

Comment: Do you know which DBMS this about?  The syntax is recognizable — but I'm not sure whether it is DB2 or some other DBMS.  If you can identify it, I can add the DBMS tag to the question.

Comment: Ah — OK.  That makes it [tag:extended-sql], I believe.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Cryostasys that was just my error... I declared the eventTimeStamp  as TIMESTAMP (not as CHARACTER) and it worked!  Thanks so much!